# Account Verification through email node js and Angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building an SPA where the user registers himself and receives an email. On the verify button click I take the token from the path and trying to send it to NodeJs

**activation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RestApiService } from '../../rest-api.service';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-activation',
  templateUrl: './activation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activation.component.css']
})
export class ActivationComponent implements OnInit {

  temporarytoken: string;
  public sub: any;

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private 
  rest: RestApiService, private data: DataService) { }  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub =this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.temporarytoken= params['temporarytoken'];
  this.updateAccount();
});

if(this.temporarytoken == null){
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
 }

 async updateAccount(){
   try{
    const data = await this.rest.post(
   'http://localhost:3030/api/accounts/activate', {
     temporarytoken: this.temporarytoken
   },
 );
} catch {
 this.data.error(['message']);
}
}

 }
```

**route Node JS**

```
router.put('/activate', (req, res, next) => {
   User.findOne({ temporarytoken: req.body.temporarytoken }, (err, user) => {
       if (err) throw err;
      var token = req.body.temporarytoken;

        jwt.verify(token, secret, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Activation Link has Expired' 
    });
        }
        else if (!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Activation Link has Expired' 
    });
        }
        else {
            user.temporarytoken = false;
            user.active = true;
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
                        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                            service: "gmail",
                            debug: true,
                            auth: {
                                user: "*******@gmail.com",
                                pass: "*********"
                            }
                        });
                        let mailOptions = {
                            from: '"Company" <********@gmail.com>""',
                            to: user.email,
                            subject: 'Welcome!!!',
                            text: 'hello account activated',
                            html: 'hello account activated'
                        };
                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                            if (error) {
                                return console.log(error);
                            }
                            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
                            console.log('emial entered', user.email);
                            console.log('Preview URL: %s', 
                    nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'Account Activated!' })
            }
          });
       });
    });
```

When I try to pass the token from postman it throws me this error

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ ReferenceError: secret is not defined
>       at User.findOne (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\routes\account.js:133:27)
>       at C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3950:16
>       at Immediate. (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1516:14)
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:119:16)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

if the secret is taken out I get this error

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
>       at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:39:17)
>       at User.findOne (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\routes\account.js:133:13)
>       at C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3950:16
>       at Immediate. (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1516:14)
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\manoj\Desktop\blue\server\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:119:16)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

How do I send the token to NodeJs

Comment: what is 'secret's value?

Comment: `secret` is the private key used to sign the JWT, you need to provide that.